# Typeahead giving me error

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

As my title says I need some help in using typeahead plugin from bootstrap. I'm new to bootstrap.
Let me show you What i have tried till now.

My HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" name="pname" id="pname" autocomplete="off">
```

my js

```
$('#pname').typeahead({
                source: function (query, process) {
                states = [];
                map = {};
                return $.get('/'+url_root_path+'/misc/purchase/source.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);  
                    return process(data.pname);
                });
                }
            });
```

My Json is

```
[{"pname":"Chettinad","id":"1"},{"pname":"mobile","id":"4"},{"pname":"iPhone","id":"14"},{"pname":"jalli","id":"15"},{"pname":"iphone5s","id":"16"},{"pname":"no image","id":"19"}]
```

My PHP code is

```
$req = "SELECT pname, id "
    ."FROM product "
    ."WHERE pname LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['query']."%' ";

$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array('pname' => $row['pname'], 'id' => $row['id'] );
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Whenever I tried to type some this in the text box. I'm getting the error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

please help me out.

Comment: after my JS I have given my json data. please have a look. @Aditya

Comment: yes. I cannot upvote. it says upvote requires 15 rep. @Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  jQuery **[$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** for your typeahead to create a `names` array out of the json object like this:

### JS:

```
   $('#pname').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
            names = [];
            map = {};
           $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                map = obj;

                if($.inArray(obj.pname, names)==-1)
                names.push(obj.pname);
            }); 
                 process(names);
            }
        });
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/7X7mw/)

Comment: thank you. working good in fiddle, but in  my browser, it is giving me error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '31' in [{"pname":"Chettinad","id":"1"}] " @Aditya

Comment: @Eric : You will have to use `$.parseJSON(data)` to parse the response as `JSON` :)

Comment: thats cool :) working fine. and I have one doubt. when I type 'Che' 3 letters. the name chettinad displays 3 times in the suggestion list. but actually it is one. Can you figure it out.

Comment: @Eric : It's not showing the like that in the fiddle ,i guess the array you are making has duplicates or probably pushed in many times . Is it? :)

Comment: nope, when I type 3 letters, it is querying, 3 letters 3 times and my php file returns 3 json output.

Comment: Accepted as answer :) By the way I have doubt in updater. updater: function(item) { var item_id = map[item].id; alert(item_id); } TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try `console.log(map[item])` and check what keys are there on that object on browser console

Comment: undefined is logging in console, when I use console.log(map[item]); your answer is my JS.

Comment: Try logging `map` and `item` and check both the objects once, then you can have a better idea

Comment: map logs: Object
3: Object
id: "3"
pname: "camera" and item logs: camera. but couldn't get the id through var item_id = map[item].id;

Comment: console.log(map.id) gives undefined

Comment: @Eric : updated answer assign `map = obj;` in $.each loop and the get map.id

Comment: again a help, ID is mismatching, when the pname is similar and ID differs.

Comment: @Eric : I'm not getting the problem, could you ask another question maybe detailing your code , thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045505/typeahead-updater-data-mismatch check here @Aditya