# typeahead updater data mismatch

Tags: json, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I tried typeahead updater for further manipulation of data. Here I go with my code. Have a look and help me out.

My HTML :

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" name="pname" id="pname" autocomplete="off">

<table id="pytable">                                                <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

My JSON :

```
[{"pname":"iPhone4","id":"14","pid":"PRO14"},{"pname":"iphone5s","id":"16","pid":"PRO16"}]
```

JS :

```
$('#pname').typeahead({
                source: function (query, process) {
                names = [];
                map = {};
                return $.get('/'+url_root_path+'/misc/purchase/source.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);    
                    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(json_obj, function (i, obj) {
                        map = obj;
                        if($.inArray(obj.pname, names)==-1)
                        names.push(obj.pname);
                    //  console.log(map);
                    }); 
                    return process(names);
                });
                }, // source

                updater: function(item) {
                //console.log(map);
                //console.log(item);
                //console.log(map.id);
            var item_code = map.pid; var item_cost = 0;
        var item_name = item;               
        var item_id = map.id;
         var newTr = $('<tr id="row_'+ count +'"></tr>');
        newTr.html('<td><input name="product'+ count +'" type="hidden" value="'+ item_code +'"><input class="span5 tran" style="text-align:left;" name="item'+ count +'" type="text" value="'+ item_name +' ('+ item_code +')"></td><td><input class="span2 tran" name="quantity'+ count +'" type="text" value="1" onClick="this.select();"></td><td><input class="span2 tran" style="text-align:right;" name="unit_cost'+ count +'" type="text" value="'+ item_cost +'"></td><td><i class="icon-trash tip del" id="'+ count +'" title="Remove this Item" style="cursor:pointer;" data-placement="right"></i></td>');
        newTr.appendTo("#pytable"); 
        } //updater

            }); //typehead
```

My problem is, when I click through the updater it append same pid for every product with similar name.

Comment: Where is `count` initialized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `obj.name` to map to to the `obj` object using `map` array :

JS:

```
$('#pname').typeahead({
 source: function (query, process) {
      names = [];
      map = {};
      return $.get('/'+url_root_path+'/misc/purchase/source.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
        var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
         $.each(json_obj, function (i, obj) {
            map[obj.pname] = obj; //<------ make this change

            if($.inArray(obj.pname, names)==-1)
            names.push(obj.pname);                   
         }); 
             return process(names);
      });
},
updater: function(item) {
  //change the below line
  var item_code = map[item]['pid'] , item_cost = 0, item_name = item , item_id = map[item]['id'];
  var newTr = $('<tr id="row_'+ count +'"></tr>');
  newTr.html('<td><input name="product'+ count +'" type="hidden" value="'+ item_code +'"><input class="span5 tran" style="text-align:left;" name="item'+ count +'" type="text" value="'+ item_name +' ('+ item_code +')"></td><td><input class="span2 tran" name="quantity'+ count +'" type="text" value="1" onClick="this.select();"></td><td><input class="span2 tran" style="text-align:right;" name="unit_cost'+ count +'" type="text" value="'+ item_cost +'"></td><td><i class="icon-trash tip del" id="'+ count +'" title="Remove this Item" style="cursor:pointer;" data-placement="right"></i></td>');
            newTr.appendTo("#pytable"); 
   } 
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/7X7mw/1/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pid' of undefined, getting this error.

Comment: @Eric Oh it was a typo , `map[item]['pid']` not `map['item']['pid']` , updated code.